# Can I have customize getter and setter for Realm in c#?

Tags: c#, realm

I have a `RealmObject` extended class. Some of its properties are declared like this:

```
public String Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
```

These are stored in the Realm data base when I save the object. For the other one, I need a custom setter like this:

```
private double _amount;
public double Amount
{
    get { return _amount; }
    set
    {
        _amount = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And this one isn't stored. Can someone help me?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 3):

Realm will only store properties that have an automatic getter and setter, because it uses compile-time IL generation to replace the implementation with calls into the database. If you want to customize the getter and setter, you need to define your fields as properties instead:

```
private double _amount { get; set; }
public double Amount
{
    get { return _amount; }
    set { ... }
}
```

Realm will use the `_amount` property, while your app can use the public `Amount` one.

On a side note, you don't need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged` for persisted properties because Realm already handles `INotifyPropertyChanged` events for you. So `public double Amount { get; set; }` is enough to raise property changed notifications.